# How to display message using connect-flash and express-messages on .dust file on Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dust.js, kraken.js

I'm using **Nodejs** and **Expressjs** and **Kraken**, I need to display message when added a product on index but I tried many time for to config but messages still not appear as I expect. Here is my config.js:

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');
app = module.exports = express();
app.use(kraken(options));
//flash
app.use(flash());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
   next();
});
```

**My controller :**

```
router.post('/somePath', function (req, res) {
//something to do to add
res.flash('messages','Add success!!')
res.render('path/index');
});
```

**My index.dust file:**

```
`{>"layouts/master" /} 
 {<body}
   {messages|s}
   // body goes here
 {/body}
```

`

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty close to the answer.

This line

```
   res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
```

Stores a function in `messages` that outputs the flash messages as an html fragment.

`res.locals` is merged by express with the models that are used to render your template.

Now you just need a way to invoke this function from within the dust template.

Doing this:

```
{messages|s}
```

Doesn't actually invoke the function.  You need to call it as if it were a context helper:

```
{#messages /}
```

You'll have one last hurdle to clear.
The function signature that `express-messages` expects, is different from what dust provides, so you'll have to wrap it within a helper function (in your server.js file):

```
app.use(flash());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
    res.locals.messages = function (chunk, context, bodies, params) {
        return chunk.write(messages());
    };
    next();
});
```